# Distrubuted storage PVC on k3s using OpenEBS is stuck in a pending status while provisioning - waiting on external provisioning, not sure why

Tags: kubernetes, storage, k3s, distributed-systems

I'm trying to setup distributed raid 1+0 storage on my k3s cluster running of 5 raspberry pi 4s running armbian (jammy).  Currently I'm seeing the event `waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "openebs.io/provisioner-raw-block" or manually created by system administrator` on my test PVC and it has been stuck provisioning in a pending state for over 24 hours now.  It seems like the worker was asked to provision... but it isn't?  I'm not sure why not.

My master node is `atlas00` and the workers are `02, 04, 05, 06`, & `08`.  I have a hdd attached to each worker mounted at `/mnt/eos<worker #/2 -1>` (so `atlas02` has a mounted drive at `/mnt/eos0` and `atlas04` has a mounted drive at `/mnt/eos1` and so on).  Below is my PVC and SC description and list of pods for OpenEBS and my nodes.  I'm not sure what all would be helpful here to troubleshoot this even.  If you have any insight into what might be going on, I'd appreciate your wisdom - thanks!

```
root@atlas00:~# kubectl describe pvc eos-pvc-test
Name:          eos-pvc-test
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  eos-raid10
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: openebs.io/provisioner-raw-block
               volume.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: openebs.io/provisioner-raw-block
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                     From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----                    ----                         -------
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning  3m16s (x5983 over 24h)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "openebs.io/provisioner-raw-block" or manually created by system administrator
root@atlas00:~# kubectl describe sc eos-raid10
Name:            eos-raid10
IsDefaultClass:  No
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"eos-raid10"},"parameters":{"cas.openebs.io/config":"- name: StorageType\n  value: \"raid-10\"\n- name: ReplicaAutoCreation\n  value: \"true\"\n","openebs.io/block-device":"[\n  {\"nodeID\": \"atlas01\", \"devicePath\": \"/dev/sda\"},\n  {\"nodeID\": \"atlas02\", \"devicePath\": \"/dev/sda\"},\n  {\"nodeID\": \"atlas03\", \"devicePath\": \"/dev/sda\"},\n  {\"nodeID\": \"atlas04\", \"devicePath\": \"/dev/sda\"}\n]\n","openebs.io/capacity":"10G","openebs.io/cstor-target-ips":"192.168.42.52,192.168.42.54,192.168.42.56,192.168.42.58","openebs.io/cstor-target-path":"/mnt/eos0,/mnt/eos1,/mnt/eos2,/mnt/eos3","openebs.io/jiva-replica-count":"4","openebs.io/jiva-replica-image":"quay.io/openebs/jiva:0.8.0","openebs.io/readwrite":"rw","openebs.io/storage-engine":"jiva","openebs.io/storage-pool":"default","openebs.io/volume-monitor":"true","targetPortal":"192.168.42.52:3260,192.168.42.54:3260,192.168.42.56:3260,192.168.42.58:3260"},"provisioner":"openebs.io/provisioner-raw-block"}

Provisioner:  openebs.io/provisioner-raw-block
Parameters:   cas.openebs.io/config=- name: StorageType
  value: "raid-10"
- name: ReplicaAutoCreation
  value: "true"
,openebs.io/block-device=[
  {"nodeID": "atlas01", "devicePath": "/dev/sda"},
  {"nodeID": "atlas02", "devicePath": "/dev/sda"},
  {"nodeID": "atlas03", "devicePath": "/dev/sda"},
  {"nodeID": "atlas04", "devicePath": "/dev/sda"}
]
,openebs.io/capacity=10G,openebs.io/cstor-target-ips=192.168.42.52,192.168.42.54,192.168.42.56,192.168.42.58,openebs.io/cstor-target-path=/mnt/eos0,/mnt/eos1,/mnt/eos2,/mnt/eos3,openebs.io/jiva-replica-count=4,openebs.io/jiva-replica-image=quay.io/openebs/jiva:0.8.0,openebs.io/readwrite=rw,openebs.io/storage-engine=jiva,openebs.io/storage-pool=default,openebs.io/volume-monitor=true,targetPortal=192.168.42.52:3260,192.168.42.54:3260,192.168.42.56:3260,192.168.42.58:3260
AllowVolumeExpansion:  <unset>
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     Immediate
Events:                <none>
root@atlas00:~# kubectl get pods -n openebs
NAME                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE
openebs-ndm-z9vqb                                 1/1     Running   0              25h
openebs-cstor-cspc-operator-86b95cb7b-9gnst       1/1     Running   0              25h
openebs-ndm-ss88z                                 1/1     Running   0              25h
openebs-ndm-6vhwk                                 1/1     Running   0              25h
openebs-ndm-operator-698457995-ppp78              1/1     Running   0              25h
openebs-cstor-cvc-operator-bf7b8d559-lhl8c        1/1     Running   0              25h
openebs-ndm-5kjtk                                 1/1     Running   0              25h
openebs-cstor-csi-node-dwsgj                      2/2     Running   0              25h
openebs-cstor-csi-node-r8tc4                      2/2     Running   0              25h
openebs-ndm-x7cbh                                 1/1     Running   0              25h
openebs-cstor-csi-node-j59q9                      2/2     Running   0              25h
openebs-cstor-csi-node-xv9th                      2/2     Running   0              25h
openebs-cstor-admission-server-7d89bb76bf-bmd2m   1/1     Running   0              25h
openebs-cstor-csi-node-xt9jv                      2/2     Running   0              25h
openebs-localpv-provisioner-7576d8cbcf-6nbl8      1/1     Running   14 (18m ago)   25h
openebs-cstor-csi-controller-0                    6/6     Running   12 (18m ago)   25h
root@atlas00:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
atlas08   Ready    worker                 26h   v1.26.3+k3s1
atlas06   Ready    worker                 26h   v1.26.3+k3s1
atlas04   Ready    worker                 26h   v1.26.3+k3s1
atlas00   Ready    control-plane,master   26h   v1.26.3+k3s1
atlas02   Ready    worker                 26h   v1.26.3+k3s1
root@atlas00:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Answer (score 1):

If users have a strict firewall setup on their Kubernetes nodes, the provisioning of a PV from a storageclass backed by a cStor storage pool may fail. The pool can be created without any issue and even the storage class is created, but the PVs may stay in pending state indefinitely. you may need to check the openebs-provisioner log.

Workaround:

This issue has currently only been observed, if the underlying node uses a network bridge and if the setting net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1 in the /etc/sysctl.conf is present. The aforementioned setting is required in some Kubernetes installations, such as the Rancher Kubernetes Engine (RKE).

To avoid this issue, open the port 5656/tcp on the nodes that run the OpenEBS API pod. Alternatively, removing the network bridge might work.

NB: this solution is from the docs and the link is:https://openebs.io/docs/main/troubleshooting/volume-provisioning#persistent-volumes-indefinitely-remain-in-pending-state